# InvalidOperationException thrown due to model of incompatible type

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am coding a Web-based movie database application using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC. I am trying to add search-by-genre capability (I already have search-by-title) but something I'm doing is causing an "InvalidOperationException".

This is from the debug console:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Using launch settings from 'C:\Users\Trevor\source\repos\ASP.NET project_3\MovieDBApp\Properties\launchSettings.json' [Profile 'MovieDBApp']...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7167
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5204
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Trevor\source\repos\ASP.NET project_3\MovieDBApp\
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MovieDBApp.Models.Movie]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MovieDBApp.Models.MovieGenreViewModel'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(Object value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary source, Object model, Type declaredModelType)
         at lambda_method66(Closure , ViewDataDictionary )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.CreateViewDataDictionary(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

In my `Models` directory, I have a file called `MovieGenreViewModel.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MovieDBApp.Models
{
    public class MovieGenreViewModel
    {
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public SelectList Genres { get; set; }
        public string MovieGenre { get; set; }
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `Index.cshtml` looks like this:

```
@model MovieDBApp.Models.MovieGenreViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method = "get">
    <p>
        <select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres"> 
            <option value="">All</option> 
        </select> 

        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].ReleaseDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Genre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Rating)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Runtime)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Movies) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Runtime)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I had to change the first line from

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieDBApp.Models.Movie>
```

to

```
@model MovieDBApp.Models.MovieGenreViewModel
```

to insert the code for the genre search:

```
<select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres"> 
    <option value="">All</option> 
</select>
```

I changed `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)` to `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Title)` (I also changed the successive attributes in the same pattern).

I'm really not sure what the problem is. I tried changing the top line to

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieDBApp.Models.MovieGenreViewModel>
```

but that causes VS Code to give an error saying,

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'MovieGenre' and no accessible extension method 'MovieGenre' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found.

**UPDATE 1** (`MoviesController.cs`):

```
namespace MovieDBApp.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MovieDBAppContext _context;

        public MoviesController(MovieDBAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Movies
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            var movies = from m in _context.Movie select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Movies/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Movies/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Rating,Runtime")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(movie);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Rating,Runtime")] Movie movie)
        {
            if (id != movie.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(movie);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MovieExists(movie.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(movie);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (movie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(movie);
        }

        // POST: Movies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Movie == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'MovieDBAppContext.Movie'  is null.");
            }

            var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);

            if (movie != null)
            {
                _context.Movie.Remove(movie);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool MovieExists(int id)
        {
          return (_context.Movie?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And controller code?

Comment: @Trevor: As the exception say, instead of passing an instance of the `MovieGenreViewModel` you are passing `MovieGenreViewModel.Movies`. Fix your `Index()` action method to pass proper model to the `View(model);`.

Comment: Did [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-6.0) can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** The Index() method needed to be updated.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                    orderby m.Genre
                                    select m.Genre;
            var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title!.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
        }

        var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
        {
            Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
            Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
        };

            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
```

Thanks to @Chen for posting a link to documentation.